# Python(Django): form write an ERROR befor submit

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to check the Form after submit, but I have ERROR MASSAGE befor it.
I thing there is a mistake at VIEW-file

**this is my views.py:**

```
    @login_required
    def post_create(request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        template = 'posts/create_post.html'
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.author = request.user
                form.save()
                return redirect('posts:profile', username=request.user.username)
        return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

**this is my HTML template:**

```
            {% if form.errors %}
                  {% for field in form %} 
                    {% for error in field.errors %}            
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ field.label }}: {{ error|escape }}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                      {{ error|escape }}
                    </div>
                  {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

your form is trying to submit when the page load. I usually prevent this using javascript.

try this:

```
<script>
    form = document.getElementById('paymentform')
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting on pageload 
    form.submit();
               
    })
</script>
```

first give your form an `id`, I gave mine `paymentform` and then paste the above code snippet at the bottom of your html file